# Looking for a way to display different text in a Modal based off of which button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on this little React project, and I have 4 buttons that have different titles for provided services. I also have a Modal that appears to give more information. I am using state to display and remove the Modal component which works fine. So I am looking for a way to pass different titles, and different sets of descriptions as props to the Modal depending on which button was pressed. I.E, if Button 4 was pressed, it would display the title and description text for Service 4.

Here is the current code I have

```js
const ServicesCard: React.FC = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const Toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  return (
    <div className={classes.ServicesCard}>
      <div className={classes.ServicesCardContainer}>
        <div className={classes.TitleContainer}>
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
          <button onClick={() => Toggle()} id="s1">
            Service 1
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => Toggle()} id="s2">
            Service 2
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => Toggle()} id="s3">
            Service 3
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => Toggle()} id="s4">
            Service 4
          </button>

          <ServiceModal show={modal} close={Toggle} title="Service">
            
          </ServiceModal>
        </div>
        <p>Click For More Info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the `onClick` method you are calling the `Toggle()` method which toggles the state of the visibility of the modal. You could do the same for title and description. For example call `ToggleService1()` in the `onClick` for Service 1 and in that method set the title, set the description and toggle the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Your course of action should be passing props of whatever you want to display in the modal to the `ServiceModal` component.

I would suggest that instead of having a `modal` state, have a `selectedService` state which starts as `null`. Then, when clicking a button, change the `selectedService` state to whatever you chose and display the modal only when `selectedService` is not `null`

It would look something along these lines

```js
const SERVICES_INFO = {
s1: {title: 'whatever', description: 'whatever'},
s2: //You get the gist
...
}


const ServicesCard: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState(false);
  const selectService = service => setSelectedService(service);
  const closeModal = () => setSelectedService(null);

  return (
    <div className={classes.ServicesCard}>
      <div className={classes.ServicesCardContainer}>
        <div className={classes.TitleContainer}>
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
          <button onClick={() => selectService("s1")} id="s1">
            Service 1
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService("s2")} id="s2">
            Service 2
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService("s3")} id="s3">
            Service 3
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService("s4")} id="s4">
            Service 4
          </button>

          <ServiceModal show={selectedService !== null} close={closeModal} serviceInfo={SERVICES_INFO[selectedService]}>
            
          </ServiceModal>
        </div>
        <p>Click For More Info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then in your `ServiceModal` component you can use the `serviceInfo` prop to render whatever you need.

Comment: Ok, I have set it up some more here, but now I am running into another problem, and I feel like it is a simple solution but cannot find it. 1. The modal turns the screen blank when the button is clicked. And I am not sure if the correct data is being sent to modal as a prop. I have asked a new question here if you have any suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666972/modal-component-and-props-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

I do not work in React Js. But I am telling you the Javascript.
Do this:

- Give IDs to your Modal Title and Text like modalTitle and modalText.
- Now, change the innerText of your title and text when a specific
  button is clicked

  ```
  modalTitle = documet.getElementById('modalTitle');
  modalText = documet.getElementById('modalText');

  //if button 1 is clicked

  s1.addEventListner('click', ()=>{
      modalTitle.innerText = 'Your Button s1 Title';
      modalText.innerText = 'Your Button s1 Text';
  })

  //if button 2 is clicked

  s2.addEventListner('click', ()=>{
      modalTitle.innerText = 'Your Button s2 Title';
      modalText.innerText = 'Your Button s2 Text';
  })
  ```

Do this for all buttons.