# Modal Component and props not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Yesterday I asked a question about sending different sets of data to a Modal component based on which button was clicked. [(Link to Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652367/looking-for-a-way-to-display-different-text-in-a-modal-based-off-of-which-button) I have made some changes and have run into a new problem, now when the Modal is activated by any button, the screen goes blank. I feel like it's a simple solution, but I'm not sure where to look. Also, I don't believe I am correctly accessing the object("title" and "desc") once it is passed into the Modal. The index.html div for the React portal is in the right spot, and I don't think its a CSS problem because I haven't done anything to it when it was working.

Current Code:

**ServicesCard**

```js
const SERVICES_INFO = {
  s1: { title: 'Service 1', desc: 'Description 1' },
  s2: { title: 'Service 2', desc: 'Description 2' },
  s3: { title: 'Service 3', desc: 'Description 3' },
  s4: { title: 'Service 4', desc: 'Description 4' },
};

const ServicesCard = () => {
  const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState(null);
  const selectService = (service) => setSelectedService(service);
  const closeModal = () => setSelectedService(null);

  return (
    <div className={classes.ServicesCard}>
      <div className={classes.ServicesCardContainer}>
        <div className={classes.TitleContainer}>
          <h2>Services</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
          <button onClick={() => selectService('s1')} id="s1">
            Service 1
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService('s2')} id="s2">
            Service 2
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService('s3')} id="s3">
            Service 3
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => selectService('s4')} id="s4">
            Service 4
          </button>

          <ServiceModal
            show={selectedService !== null}
            close={closeModal}
            serviceInfo={SERVICES_INFO[selectedService]}
          />
        </div>
        <p>Click For More Info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**ServiceModal**

```js
const ServiceModal = (props) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <>
      {props.show ? (
        <div className={classes.modalContainer} onClick={() => props.close()}>
          <div className={classes.modal} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <header className={classes['modal_header']}>
              <h2> {props.serviceInfo} </h2>
              <hr />
            </header>
            <div className={classes['modal_content']}>
              <main> {props.serviceInfo} </main>
            </div>
            <footer className={classes.Footer}>
              <button
                className={classes['modal-close']}
                onClick={() => props.close()}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>,
    document.getElementById('modal')
  );
};
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you pass functions to the child component is wrong. It should be something like :

```
const PageComponent = () => {
  const handleClickOnButton = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  return ( 
    <Button handleClick={handleClickOnButton}>;
  )
}

const ButtonComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>;
  )
}
```

Then, i would recommend to add a state in your parent component just to manage the opening/closing of the modal. Something like :

```
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
```

and you add conditionnal statement checking this state to know if you show your modal or not :

```
  { modalOpen &&
    <ServiceModal
      show={selectedService !== null}
      close={closeModal}
      serviceInfo={SERVICES_INFO[selectedService]}
    />
  }
```

It may won't solve everything, but that's a good start i would say

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render an object on your modal component, and React can't render objects. What you should change is:

```js
 <h2> {props.serviceInfo.title} </h2>
 <main> {props.serviceInfo.desc} </main>
```

As those are strings, they can be rendered